# Helm - Check if value not exists OR part of list

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

Assuming I have this values.yaml under my helm chart -

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: test-production-dev
    env:
      - production
      - dev
  - name: test-dev
    env:
      - dev
  - name: test-all

environment_variables:
  STAGE: dev
```

I would like to run my cronjob based on these values -

- if `.env` doesn't exist - run any time.
- if `.env` exists - run only if `environment_variables.STAGE` is in the `.env` list.

This is what I've done so far ( with no luck ) -

```yaml
{{- range $.Values.tasks}}
# check if $value.env not exists OR contains stage
{{if or .env (hasKey .env "$.Values.environment_variables.STAGE")  }}
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
...
{{- end}}
---
{{- end}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

values.yaml

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: test-production-dev
    env:
      - production
      - dev
  - name: test-dev
    env:
      - dev
  - name: test-all
  - name: test-production
    env:
      - production

environment_variables:
  STAGE: dev
```

template/xxx.yaml

plan a

```yaml
...
{{- range $.Values.tasks }}
{{- $flag := false }}
{{- if .env }}
{{- range .env }}
{{- if eq . $.Values.environment_variables.STAGE }}
{{- $flag = true }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- else }}
{{- $flag = true }}
{{- end }}
{{- if $flag }}
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
meta:
  name: {{ .name }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
...
```

plan b

```yaml
...
{{- range $.Values.tasks }}
{{- if or (not .env) (has $.Values.environment_variables.STAGE .env) }}
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
meta:
  name: {{ .name }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
...
```

output

```yaml
...
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
meta:
  name: test-production-dev
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
meta:
  name: test-dev
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
meta:
  name: test-all
...
```

Comment: Working like a charm ! 
i wonder if we can have this logic in one line.

Comment: As you wish, see the updated plan b above